# Can I use data grid over WAN?

Tags: gridgain

I am new for GridGain and currently I am using GridGain 6.20(open source version). I am wondering if I can use data grid over WAN(through Internet, across multiple data centers).

For example, I have four nodes: N1, N2, N3 and N4. N1 and N2 are in San Jose Data Center. N3 and N4 are in San Francisco Data Center. I plan to build a data grid(a cluster) including N1, N2, N3 and N4. As you can see, it is over WAN.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this:

1. Simply open ports over WAN. GridGain will work, but this is probably not too kosher from security standpoint.
2. Open VPN connection between data centers and use standard GridGain configuration.
3. If you are using multiple data centers for fail-over purposes, then you can use GridGain Data Center Replication feature - http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Data+Center+Replication